# Probability - House Street Numbers

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If I was to pick a random house with a numbered street address
e.g. 1600 Pennsylvania Ave

Is there a natural probability distribution that these house numbers would conform to? If so what would it be?

[I'm trying to build a realistic random street address generator]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Put all possible addresses in an array and select one uniformly. If you want a more efficient solution, first select the street, weighted by the number of addresses on that street, then select an address.

Comment: @AleksejsFomins I don't have any actual data yet, That's why I'm trying to generate some fake data.

Comment: I understand that. But it is important to know what is the extent of the randomness you are looking for: what are the possible street names? what are the possible house numbers? is there an equal number of houses on each street? These parameters will affect the fake data you intend to generate.

Comment: So my question was more about what the shape of the distribution of house numbers would be if we took all the street addresses in the world - would house numbers fall into a known probability distribution fn.